# Trying to shorten URLs using .htaccess, but hitting configuration errors

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

Brief intro: I'm attempting to set up a short URL system using a database and php. I've however came across a much shorter/quicker approach using a .htaccess file, regex, and a local config file. This tutorial however doesn't offer much support or explanation, and it's the first instance of URL re-writing I've seen.

Here's the code for the php script that gets the arguments passed into the page:

```
<?php

$links = parse_ini_file('links.ini');

if(isset($_GET['l']) && array_key_exists($_GET['l'], $links))
{
    header('Location: ' . $links[$_GET['l']]);
}
else
{
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    echo 'Unknown link.';
}

?>
```

So in other words it checks to see if the argument passed is in the static config file (example here would be google: http://example.com/index.php?l=google), and if so, then of course re-directs them to the site. Configuration file contents:

```
google  = https://www.google.com/
fb      = https://www.facebook.com/
```

Fairly logical. Can understand how it works. My problem however comes with the .htaccess file as mentioned above. I've only dabbled with regex, and plan to learn more. However currently I'm not skilled enough to really understand the syntax required to write what is needing to be achieved. What needs to happen is for the user to basically type in www.example.com/url/google and for them to be re-directed to www.example.com/url/index.php?l=google - this is something I've been unable to get to work, and I just receive web server config errors. Config file for .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?l=$1 [L]
```

Can anyone advise on the cause of the issue? Sorry for the lack of understanding on the regex part. I'm trying to skill up on it. I'd just like to get the fix in place so I can continue on my project, as it's only a small part of it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Indeed. It's within an accessible virtual host, and contains an index.php file. All files are owned by the apache user too.

Comment: Using rewrite is generally a terrible idea, because if the "l=" happens in a different position your rewrite completely fails.

Comment: When you say the 'l=' being in different position, what do you mean? As the re-direct would merely grab the string they have requested, and then compare it and pass it as an argument into a url always containing the 'l='?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will redirect it:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/url/([a-z]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /url/index.php?l=%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?l=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sadly I've copied the above configuration word for word, and it's still diverting me to a configuration error page. Have you tested this yourself?

Comment: Tested again and works. Does the original rewrite work (the bottom two lines)? Or does that throw an error too? You need to have the Apache module mod_rewrite loaded in order for this to work. If you have mod_rewrite loaded - is there any other code in your .htaccess besides what you posted?

Comment: Dear oh dear. Being so new to Apache, I was completely unaware of the fact that modules had to be disabled/enabled. I'd read it came installed with it (re-write module), but had no idea it was disabled out of the box. Quickly enabling it resolved the issue. Bet the initial config would of worked too!

So much for useful tutorials ay... thanks a lot Jeroen.

Comment: Great, now you can move on to the next challenge :-)